# Can't change materials in Blender 2.8

Tags: texturing, uv-image-editor

I was modelling an item in Blender and I wanted to change the rust **texture**, so I removed the **texture** I had [image: Image texture removed]

I then went on to add a different **texture**, but the **texture** didn't change to the new image 
[image: Image texture didn't change]

is there anything i can do

Comment: you need to look at the Material to make sure that the right one is assigned to your object and also at the Shader editor to make sure the nodes are correctly organized